# what should I add on this script to make the transition fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var i =0; 0 <= i; i++)
function f() {
    $('#clickbtn').click()
    i++;
    if (i < 2100) {
        setTimeout( f, 2500);
    }
}
f();
```

it works fine but I can notice a quick pause before the next click. what should I add to make the click automatically pressed upon loading of the button.

thanks in advance guys

Comment: `var i =0; 0 <= i; i++)` <-- what is that

Comment: No clue what you are talking about. Are you complaining about the  2.5 seconds with the timeout??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clear idea what you're trying to do. Click a button a whole bunch? `2099` times maybe?

This might be what you're trying to do, if you're even trying to click a button a bunch.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    for (i=0;i<2100;i++){
       $('#clickbtn').click()
    }
    clearTimeout(timer)
    location.reload();
},3000);
```

This will SMASH button clicks, reload the page, and do it all again.